# What does it mean for a value to "have a functor"?

Tags: category-theory, fantasyland

I'm new to this, and I may be missing something important. I've read part one of [Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/), but the most abstract math I did in university was Group Theory so I'm having to read very slowly.

I would ultimately like to understand the theory to ground my use of the techniques, so whenever I feel like I've made some progress I return to the fantasy-land spec to test myself. This time I felt like I knew where to start: I started with Functor.

From the [fantasy-land spec](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor):

> **Functor**
>
> 1. `u.map(a => a)` is equivalent to `u` (identity)
> 2. `u.map(x => f(g(x)))` is equivalent to `u.map(g).map(f)` (composition)
>
> **`map` method**
>
> ```
> map :: Functor f => f a ~> (a -> b) -> f b
> ```
>
> A value which *has a Functor* must provide a map method. The map method takes one argument:
>
> ```
> u.map(f)
> ```
>
> 1. f must be a function,
>
>    i. If f is not a function, the behaviour of map is unspecified.
>
>    ii.f can return any value.
>
>    iii. No parts of f's return value should be checked.
> 2. map must return a value of the same Functor

I don't understand the phrase "a value which *has a functor*".

What does it mean for a value to "have a functor"? I don't think "is a functor" or "belongs to a functor" would make any more sense here.

What is the documentation trying to say about `u`?

---

My understanding is that a functor is a mapping between categories (or in this case from a category to itself). We are working in the category of types, in which objects are types and morphisms are families of functions that take a type to another type, or a type to itself.

As far as I can tell, a functor maps `a` to `Functor a`. It has some kind of constructor like,

```
Functor :: a -> F a
```

and a map function like,

```
map :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The `a` refers to *any type*, and the family of functions `(a -> b)` refers to all morphisms pointing from any particular type `a` to any other particular type `b`. So it doesn't even really make sense to me to distinguish between values which do or do not "have a functor" because if at least one functor exists, then it exists "for" every type... so every value can be mapped by a function that belongs to a morphism between two types that has been lifted by a functor. What I mean is: please show me an example of a value which "does not have a functor".

The functor *is* the mapping; it isn't the type `F a`, and it isn't values of the type `F a`. So in the docs, the value `u` is not a functor, and I don't think it "has a" functor... it is a value of type `F a`.

Comment: taking your own definitions, a value which has a mapping between categories

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question.

Comment: I acknowledge that this is abstract, but I hesitate to agree that this _is no_ a programming question. If the question was instead "what does it mean for a value to have a method" or "what does it mean for a value to have a type" would that be a programming question?

Comment: @RaymondChen although, on rereading my question, it does feel like it belongs in a discussion somewhere. Like, the only person equiped to answer this is the person who wrote the docs... so maybe vote to close!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, a functor in programming is a mapping between types, but JavaScript has not types, so you have to imagine them. Here, imagine that the function `f` goes from type `a` to type `b`. The value `u` is the result of some functor `F` acting on `a`. The result of `u.map(f)` is of the type `F b`, so you have a mapping from `F a` (that's the type of `u`) to `F b`. Here, `map` is treated as a method of `u`.

That's as close as you can get to a functor in JavaScript. (It doesn't help that the same letter `f` is alternatively used for the function and the functor in the documentation.)

Comment: Bartosz Milewski! Thank you for your writing/videos! 

The structure of the category of types is preserved by the functor, so if there are arrows from `a` to any other type, there will be arrows from `F a` in the same manner. If there is some `a -> b` then there is also `F a -> F b` and so on. We know this once we prove there exists a functor which maps `a` to `F a`. I feel like the docs would be more clear if they said "Given a type `F a`, there exists a functor that maps `a` to `F a` if and only if instances of `F a` implement a method `map` with the following properties:" Or something...